# Add Unique ID to Menu Item

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

Is it possible to add a unique id or class to each li element in a menu, perhaps using a preprocess function? I want to be able to target each menu item individually with CSS.

I could probably use css rules like `li:nth-child(1)` etc, but I would rather add a unique ID or class to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/link_attributes

It allows you to add classes/ids to menu items by editing them through Drupal's core menu admin screens

Answer (score 0):

You can use [menus_attribute](https://www.drupal.org/project/menus_attribute) to add MANUALLY unique ids to each menu. I understand this is not practical if you have a big menu but sometimes just setting 1 or 2 unique ids is enough for CSS design purposes.

The alternative would be to use a `THEMENAME_preprocess_menu` in your `THEMENAME.theme` file.  Drupal 8 is not easy to get `mlid` which is unique and don't change with reordering of menu items but I don't know an easy way to do it. So presenting a few options inside comments in the function itself.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_menu(array &$variables) {
  $id = 0;
  foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
    $attribute = &$variables['items'][$key]['attributes'];

    //$key might change if the link is pointing to another place
    //but is also a very ugly id and some times very big
    //$attribute->setAttribute('id', $key);

    //so to get a smaller id from previous key 
    //use http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php
    $key_hash = hash('crc32b', $key);
    $attribute->setAttribute('id', $key_hash);

    //id will change once the order of menu items changes
    //or when items are added or deleted
    //$attribute->setAttribute('id', "id-" . ++$id);    

    //how does one get them mlid from the database which would stay the same no matter what
    //probably using a function call that uses 
    //https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x

    // can this be used ? 
    //http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/8 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems like Drupal 8 is more difficult than Drupal 7 for doing this. I think I will just go with using the menu attributes module.